# flowplayer hide video display for mp3 player

Tags: javascript, audio, controller, flash, flowplayer

how can i hide video display, im just trying to display controlbar only for audios. btw im using [javascript control bar](http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/javascript/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the player-swf into a separate div ( `<div id="flash">` ), whenever you'd like to hide the output just execute `document.getElementById("flash").style.display = "none";` and `document.getElementById("flash").style.display = "block";` to show it again.

Answer (score 0):

Embed your flash player into a `<div id="player"><!-- your flash player here --></div>`. Use these styles for it:

```
#player {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

But never use `display: none;` to hide it because the flash player does not work in this way.